# Intermediate Ubuntu Books?

Tags: 13.10, books

I'm new to Ubuntu and looking for some good books to help me use it to it's full strength. However, after quite a bit of searching, I haven't found anything suitable.

Most books are for absolute beginners, covering stuff like installing the OS, basic system settings, getting around with Unity - all of which I've figured out already.
On the other end of the spectrum are the advanced books, that I'm frankly unable to follow, because I'm rather new to Ubuntu, and linux in general.

What I'm looking for is a book that can bridge the gap between these two categories.

Comment: Probably this link might help : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CommandLineResources I am in the same situation as you and the ebooks there seem to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Ubuntu pocket guide this book is much to beginners and less for the advanced users

http://www.ubuntupocketguide.com/download_main.html

Comment: Just the sort of thing I was looking for. Thank you!